# Shifted GNDA in Series DC/DC Converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I have 13 \$\pm 15V \$ DC/DC  converters and 1 \$\pm 5V\$ DC/DC converters which I am connecting in series to generate a \$\pm 200V\$ output giving a total output range of 400V. The problem is what would be the best arrangement in the PCB/layout so that I get the analog GND centered at 0V (200V for single output)? As per my arrangement, I am getting a shifted GNDA at 210V.

I also have 1 extra \$\pm 5V \$ dc/dc converter which could be used for this purpose.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: \$13 \times 15 + 2 \times 5 \ne 200\$ :)

Comment: Thanks Nidhin...obviously you know that...The point is to say there is 1 extra 5V dc converter which can be used in some way for this gnda purpose.

Comment: This is the definition of madness. Find or build a proper supply. Stacking a whole bunch of DC/DC convertors together like this is a disaster waiting to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in luck. Start at one end, and call it -200. Now stack 6 +/- 15 V converters. The top of the stack is now -20. If you add both your +/- 5 converters the top of the stack is now at 0, which is what you want. Problem is, your remaining 7 converters will produce a top end of +210.

Now for the fortunate part: since you do have a spare +/- 5 converter, the change is simple. After you get to 0 volts, add a +/- 5 unit, but only use half of it, to produce +5. Then add your remaining +/- 15 units, but only use half of the top converter. This will add 195 volts to your +5, and the result is +200.

All this, of course, assumes your +/- 15 units really are +/- 15. This is probably not a great idea, particularly under varying loads, although you'll need to check this out. The resulting tolerances may or may not meet your needs.

And I'd check very carefully on the specs for your converters. The number you want is "isolation voltage". If it is not greater than 400 volts you are risking massive failure.

Comment: what do you mean by "use half of it"? Is it like doing voltage subtraction by tying the pins in reverse?

Comment: No, when I say, use half of it, I mean that, if you have a +/- 15 volt converter, it will have 3 outputs: +15, -15 and common. Instead of connecting to +15 and -15 (which would give you 30 volts), connect to common and +15, which will give you 15 volts.